# Upload to S3 Bucket Giving Access Denied from ECS Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, aws-sdk-nodejs

I've been trying to set up simple S3 image uploading functionality for my webapp that's running in ECS. The ECS cluster was set up by a systems administrator that I no longer have help from, but every upload request is returning this error:

```
{ AccessDenied: Access Denied
at Request.extractError (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/services/s3.js:585:35)
at Request.callListeners (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
at Request.emit (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at Request.emit (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
at Request.emit (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:683:14)
at Request.transition (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
at /www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
at Request.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
at Request.<anonymous> (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:685:12)
at Request.callListeners (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
at callNextListener (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:96:12)
at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/www/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/event_listeners.js:299:13)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:423:31)
at Zone.runTask (/www/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-node.js:195:47)
message: 'Access Denied',
code: 'AccessDenied',
region: null,
time: 2019-07-25T20:59:24.717Z,
requestId: '5E0BB7DDFAF2013F',
extendedRequestId:
'UAFzo69NlfPqSIXKUUIrpvBqdj97v/xMfOxdbRfFK2rLuO06Sb/zmjTxA5/beimDuEEaq53ntdk=',
cfId: undefined,
statusCode: 403,
retryable: false,
retryDelay: 70.57095033673187 }
```

The code making the request is:

```
import S3 = require('aws-sdk/clients/s3');

config.update({ region: 'us-west-2' });
const s3 = new S3();
...
private async handleLogoUpload(id: string, dto: UpdateCustomerDto): Promise<string> {
    const filePath = `${TMP_DIR}/${dto.logoUrl[0].name}`;
    const logoFile = await readAsync(filePath);
    const uploadData = await s3.upload({
      Key: id, Bucket: 'sm-logo', Body: logoFile, ACL: 'public-read',
    }).promise();
    return deleteAsync(filePath).then(() => uploadData.Location);
  }
```

I've tried everything in this article here: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-403-upload-bucket/

The ECS instance task-execution role has this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Bucket itself has public read/write permissions.

I added an endpoint to S3 to the VPC.

The VPC allows all outbound traffic and another container on the VPC can access S3 without issue.

I'm at my wits end. Nothing I tried above has worked and I can't seem to find others with similar problems. It works locally, so I assume it's a network issue, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: Are you able to log into the ECS instance and use the AWS CLI to test permissions? Try `aws s3 ls s3://sm-logo` and `aws s3 cp file.txt s3://sm-logo/`. This way we can determine whether it is related to permissions, networking or the code.

Comment: Had to install aws-cli in the container, but after doing so I was able to list and cp

Comment: I wonder whether `public-read` is causing a problem? If the bucket has been configured with Amazon S3 Block Public Access, this might be denied. Can you try removing the ACL to see if it works?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. That was it! It now uploads without issue, but the object is not publicly accessible anymore. Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

By default, [Amazon S3 Block Public Access – Another Layer of Protection for Your Accounts and Buckets | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-block-public-access-another-layer-of-protection-for-your-accounts-and-buckets/) will block buckets and objects from being publicly accessible.

You can selectively turn off this functionality to allow:

- Bucket Policies (which apply to the whole bucket)
- Object ACLs (Access Control Lists), which apply only to an object

Only use a Bucket Policy if you are okay with all content (or a sub-directory) being publicly accessible.

The reason it worked from the AWS CLI was that it did not specify `--acl public-read`. However, when the code specified `ACL: 'public-read'`, the request was blocked.

Therefore, you should **turn off these options**:

- *Block public access to buckets and objects granted through **new** access control lists (ACLs)*
- *Block public access to buckets and objects granted through **any** access control lists (ACLs)*

Comment: Hey John, all of those options are currently off but the uploaded upload is still not publicly accessible

Comment: Did you use `ACL: 'public-read'` this time? If you access it in the S3 console, does it work with the "Open" button? Does it work if you just click the link (without a button)? If you manually mark it as "Make Public" in the Actions menu, does that fix it?

Comment: I didn't use `ACL: 'public-read'`. Even with "Block all public access" set to off it still fails on upload. It works if I open and download the file, not if I just click the public link. If I manually set it to "Public" the public link begins to work

Comment: There are two ways to make it public: Either by using a bucket policy (applies to all files in the bucket, or a particular sub-directory), or by using `ACL: 'public-read'` as you have in your code above. If you took it out of your code, put it back in.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correct then I think you have to pass task role in the task definition with proper S3 permission instead of the passing permission to the task execution role.

Because as per my understanding while making the api call from application running inside the container task role [1] is used not task execution role. Even after doing this if it is not working then we may try to test the same role using aws cli from local machine to see if it has the proper permission to upload the object to s3.

[1] Amazon ECS Task Role -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html